# API qrcode Google não reconhece o sinal +

Tags: http, google-api

Estou usando uma API do Google para gerar qr code. Porém a imagem gerada não está exibindo o caracter "+". Ele troca por espaço.
Como exemplo segue:

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=12345678901234567892Testeagora+teste+Sinal
```

Esta instrução retorna um qrcode sem os caracteres do sinal +

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Olá Leandro !  Consegui resolver sim a partir da sua resposta. Muito Obrigado! Desculpe pois sou novo aqui. Pensei que bastava eu clicar como positivo na sua resposta e já estaria indicado isso, além de ter acrescentado pontos a sua reputação. Caso seja necessário mais alguma ação de minha parte é só me indicar. Mais uma vez muito obrigado !

Comment: Na verdade não é só pela reputação, se você votar positivamente e aceitar como resposta à sua pergunta, isso facilita para que outras pessoas que passem pelo mesmo problema encontrem a solução de forma mais fácil e rápida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na URL Decode o sinal `+`  está representando um espaço, assim como o `%20`, se você quer garantir explicitamente o seu valor como  `+`, substitua por `%2B`

```
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chl=12345678901234567892Testeagora%2Bteste%2BSinal
```